# String woes in C# - having a . next to a "

Tags: c#, escaping

I have the following string:

```
string text = @"<a href=""http://raustdsx0700.real.local:7782/analytics/saw.dll?PortalPages&PortalPath=" + dashboardURL + "&Page=" + reportName + @"&P0=1&P1=eq&P2=Project.""Project Name"" target=""_blank"">" + reportName + "</a><br/><br/>";
```

When this string gets written to my page, it looks like this:

```
<a href="http://raustdsx0700.real.local:7782/analytics/saw.dll?PortalPages&PortalPath=/shared/Real Estate Reporting_portal/REGIS:  Financial Reporting UAT/&Page=DR - 3: Debt Payment History&P0=1&P1=eq&P2=Project\."Project Name" target="_blank">DR - 3: Debt Payment History</a>
```

Can someone help explain why the period id being escaped? I'm fumbling with how to escape this properly.

Thanks.

Comment: interesting issue, but why not just change it? Project" + ".\"" + @"Project

Comment: This is why FxCop whines when you use a literal instead of a Uri.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what your output should look like but
[String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) and [escaping](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31938&seqNum=9) are your friend.

```
string text = String.Format("<a href='http://raustdsx0700.real.local:7782/analytics/saw.dll?PortalPages&PortalPath={0}&Page={1}&P0=1&P1=eq&P2=Project.\"Project Name\"'' target='_blank'>{1}</a><br/><br/>",dashboardURL,reportName);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are intent on using quotes in your URL, then use single-quotes for your tag attributes.

```
string text = "<a href='http://raustdsx0700.real.local:7782/analytics/saw.dll?PortalPages&PortalPath=" + dashboardURL + "&Page=" + reportName + "&P0=1&P1=eq&P2=Project.\"Project Name\"' target='_blank'>" + reportName + "</a><br/><br/>";
```

Or better, url-escape the quote (`%22`):

```
string text = "<a href='http://raustdsx0700.real.local:7782/analytics/saw.dll?PortalPages&PortalPath=" + dashboardURL + "&Page=" + reportName + "&P0=1&P1=eq&P2=Project.%22Project Name%22' target='_blank'>" + reportName + "</a><br/><br/>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to *urlencode* your string, check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx